# adding the new view according to the finger touch location in iPhone using UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

To all
I am using the

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer*singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doSingleTap:)] autorelease];
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap
```

for getting the touch

And  in doSingleTap: method i have this

```
-(void)doSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"location X =>%f,location  =>%f ",point.x,point.y);
    CGPoint point1 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"location X =>%f,location  =>%f ",point1.x,point1.y);

     NSLog(@"location X =>%f,location  =>%f ",x,y);
    UIView *test1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(point.x, point1.y, x, y)];
    test1.backgroundColor= [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:test1];


}
```

getting the problem in adding the new view on the main view according to the finger location  or position View is properly getting  add on the view according to the position .

I want that view get add according to the two finger and automatically adjust their (x,y,w,h).
I need help  if any one help me 
Thanks in advance  I google on this but didn't get any help

Comment: what is the value of x & y in CGRectMake?

Comment: I just add the x position according to the 1st finger and y according to the 2nd finger but i think it was wrong @Rafeek

Comment: did you get any error?..

Comment: NO But new view add on the wrong place not in between  the two fingers

Comment: i didn't get you How can i use this

Comment: that was my mistake i think there is only one touch

Comment: That was my mistake I thought that there is only one touch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28976/discussion-between-rafeek-and-harish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare with point.x and point1.x take lesser 1 as x and do same for y (compare with point.y and point1.y smaller 1 as y). take the difference between point.x and point1.x as width and do same for height (difference between point.y and point1.y) will sove the issue

Comment: OK If get the (W,H)BUt now about the (?,?,W,H)

Comment: compare point.x and point1.x take small one as x, also compare point.y and  point1.y and lesser as y, then 'CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)'

Comment: while taking height and width must check its +ve or -ve if -ve then convert to +ve

Comment: if(point.x>point1.x)
    {
        locx = point1.x;
    }
    if(point.x<point1.x)
    {
        locx = point.x;
    }
    if(point.y>point1.y)
    {
        locy = point1.y;
    }
    if(point.y<point1.y)
    {
        locy = point.y;
    }
    locW = point.x-point1.x;
    locH = point.y-point1.y;
    UIView *test1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(locx,locy, locW, locH)];
    test1.backgroundColor= [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:test1];

Comment: position not get set properly

Comment: take the absolute value of width and height using 'fabsf()'

Answer (score 1):

```
float x = (point.x < point1.x) ? point.x : point1.x;
float y = (point.y < point1.y) ? point.y : point1.y;
float width = fabsf(point.x - point1.x);
float height = fabsf(point.y - point1.y);
UIView *test1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y,width,height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate rect of view with the next:

```
float x = MIN(point.x, point1.x);
float y = MIN(point.y, point1.y);
float width = fabsf(point.x - point1.x);
float height = fabsf(point.y - point1.y);
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```